# Finding collinear vector given length

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given vector A= (1, 7, -4) find a vector U that has length equal to 8 in the same direction as A. Write answer in form (u1, u2, u3).

I know that length is equal to magnitude of a vector so
8 = ||U||
Being in the same direction as a means that A and U are collinear.

Which formula can I use to find U?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  you have $U=xA=(x,7x,-4x)$.  Compute the length of $U$ as a function of $x$ and choose $x$ so the length is $8$

Comment: I got U = (8/sqrt 66 , 56/sqrt 66 , -32/sqrt 66)

Comment: That is correct.  To get square roots you do \sqrt {66} to get $\sqrt{66}$